# Ida permission error

Tags: ida, debuggers, error

I tried debugging an running a program via ida64 and it says permission denied please reopen with elevated permission. I am on a mac please tell me how to fix this[image]

Comment: Then run IDA with same permissions/privileges.

Comment: But how to run it with the needed premission